# How to handle msg when the app is in background but the user doesn’t click the received notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I know the following.
1. FCM Payload comes in the onMessageReceived() when the app is the foreground. 
2. Payload comes in the Intent Extras when the app is in the background. But only when the user clicks the notification. What if the user jumps directly in the app without interacting with the notification?
How to handle the payload in that scenario.

The payload I'm sending.

```html
{
 "registration_ids" : ["FCM Token Here"],
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "Testing FCM Message Handling",
     "title": "This is a test to handle FCM Messages inside the App"
 },
 "data" : {
     "body" : "Testing FCM Message Handling",
     "title": "This is a test to handle FCM Messages inside the App",
     "sender_member_id" : "63",
     "sender_name" : "Chiranjeev Jain"
 }
}
```

The onMessageReceived() implementation.

```html
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        //Here notification is recieved from server
        try {
            // TODO: Handle Incoming Message
            String fcmMessageTitle = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
            String fcmMessageBody = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
            String fcmSenderMemberID = remoteMessage.getData().get("sender_member_id");
            String fcmSenderName = remoteMessage.getData().get("sender_name");
            Toast.makeText(this, fcmMessageTitle + "\n" + fcmMessageBody + "\n" + fcmSenderMemberID + "\n" + fcmSenderName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also store the payload in local storage (sqlite, SharedPreferences, whatever you prefer), query that storage on app startup, and react according to what's found there.

Comment: The onMessageReceived() is not triggered when the app is in the background. How do I get the data.

Comment: It is for all messages with a data payload.  If you're using notification type messages without a data payload, then what you're trying to do isn't possible.  So use a message with a data payload. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages

Comment: I have a data payload attached. Please find the payload in the question.

Comment: Ohh I just figured that removing the notification object and the onMessageReceived() is triggered now. Is that really how its supposed to work?

Comment: I think the documentation is clear.  If it's not working as described there, please file an issue with Firebase support.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get callback `onMessageReceived()` when app is in background then send only payload. Remove notification from your `json` structure

```
{
 "registration_ids" : ["FCM Token Here"],

 "data" : {
     "body" : "Testing FCM Message Handling",
     "title": "This is a test to handle FCM Messages inside the App",
     "sender_member_id" : "63",
     "sender_name" : "Chiranjeev Jain"
 }
}
```